# char array and pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int syn(char *pc[], char, int);
int main ()
{
    char *pc[20];
    char ch;
    cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
    cin>>*pc;
    cout<<"Type The character:" << endl;
    cin>>ch;
    int apotelesma = syn(&pc[0], ch, 20);
    cout<< "There are " << apotelesma << " " << ch << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
int syn(char *pc[],char ch, int n){
    int i;
    int metroitis=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (*pc[i]==ch){
           metroitis++;
        }
    }
    return metroitis;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with that? Its not responding when it gets inside the if clause.

Comment: Are you sure you want an array of pointers to characters? It kind of looks like you're just using it like a character array.

Comment: I think you need just an array of char: char pc[20], not char *pc[20]

Comment: yes,you are right.thats one of my mistakes.I want my array[20] to be sent with pointer to the function.Then in the function syn,i want to do the search on the array.Now i changed the syn:
int syn(char *pc,char ch, int n) but it has error in the if loop. 
Invalid type argument of unary *

Answer (score 1):

Your "pc" variable is an array of 20 pointers to characters (essentially an array of 20 strings).

If you must use pointers, try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int syn(char *pc, char, int);
int main ()
{
    char *pc = new char[20];
    char ch;
    cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
    cin>>pc;
    cout<<"Type The character:" << endl;
    cin>>ch;
    int apotelesma = syn(pc, ch, strlen(pc));
    cout<< "There are " << apotelesma << " " << ch << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
int syn(char *pc,char ch, int n){
    int i;
    int metroitis=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (pc[i]==ch){
           metroitis++;
        }
    }
    return metroitis;
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? you declare `char *pc = new char[20];` but you don't release it (you let the OS do it).

Answer (score 0):

modify some codes. try it

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int syn(char pc[], char, int);
int main ()
{
    char pc[20];
    char ch;
    cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
    cin>>pc;
    cout<<"Type The character:" << endl;
    cin>>ch;
    int apotelesma = syn(pc, ch, 20);
    cout<< "There are " << apotelesma << " " << ch << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
int syn(char pc[],char ch, int n){
    int i;
    int metroitis=0;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        if (pc[i]==ch){
           metroitis++;
        }
    }
    return metroitis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char *pc[20];` This means `pc` is array of size 20, which can hold 20 pointers to `char`.  In your program you need to store only one string or text (whatever) in that variable `pc`, so why its declared to hold 20 strings(`20 pointer to char`).

Now `pc` array in your program is not `NULL` setted also. So `pc` is pointing to some 20 garbage values. Its totally wrong. `cin` will tries to write the date from `stdin` to some junk pointer in the first index of the `pc` array.

So `cin>>*pc;` in your program will leads to crash or some other memory corruption.

Change your program in any one of the way

1st way

```
 char *pc[20] = {0};
 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
      pc[i] = new char[MAX_TEXT_SIZE];
 }
 cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
 cin>>pc[0];
```

2nd way

```
 char *pc = new char[MAX_TEXT_SIZE];
 cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
 cin>>pc;
```

3rd way

```
 char pc[MAX_TEXT_SIZE];
 cout<<"Type the text" << endl;
 cin>>pc;
```

NOTE : Take care of `NULL` check for return of malloc